# Download a file with javascript and ignore MIME

Tags: javascript, html, mime

I wants browser to download a video as file as soon as when server is ready.

I have seen [Download File Using Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery) , however,It is not possible to change MIME on my server.

But some browser will regard video as a streaming media and display it at hidden iframe,instead of download it.

How can I fix this,make browser ignore MIME and download it?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, [HTML5 download attribute](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download) is what you need? Give client a link to the video and add the attribute to it.
Not every [browser supports](http://caniuse.com/download) it, though.